# Create a completely new sensor type

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to create a Doppler Velocity Log (DVL) sensor that would simply contain 4 RaySensor and a Pose element. In every tutorial that I saw about SensorPlugins, people used existing sensors and extended them. Is it possible to create a completely new sensor type ( `<sensor type="dvl" name="super_name"> ... </sensor>` )and add it to gazebo instead of using an existing sensor type and extending it? Google doesn't help me to answer this question unfortunately

Assuming that it is possible to create a new Sensor Type, is it possible to create RaySensor objects directly from a .cpp file instead of having to create them with an sdf file? If I look at the [documentation for RaySensor](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/7.1.0/classgazebo_1_1sensors_1_1RaySensor.html), it seems that we can only define the value of some attributes of a RaySensor (like the ray counts or the min-max ranges for example that only have getters but no setters) by using the RaySensor::load(...) function. Isn't there any other possibility to create a RaySensor object directly in c++ and passing the ray-counts and some other value in a constructor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20325/create-a-completely-new-sensor-type/) by [Tekkk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6382/tekkk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-08-29**:
This are to many questions :P. Okay first what do you mean with "a Pose Element"? Second i think and totally recommend to create a new sensor plugin. Should be possible to create a plugin that holds 4 RaySensors. For creating a new sensor you will need more time and better knowledge. Wouldn't recommend.

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-08-29**:
4th you can create a RaySensor in your Cpp take a look here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f4e51e8f64001beda70615ab8982a7d5a4e65b18/gazebo/sensors/RaySensor_TEST.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

**Comment by [maikelo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6309/maikelo/) on 2018-10-31**:
Were you able to make a new type of sensor? I also want to create a new sensor but I don't see yet how to link the new sensor class into Gazebo. Any clue will be appreciated. Thanks.

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-11-02**:
I've just read your other question: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20324/unable-to-create-sensor-of-type/

i think you want to use: GZ_REGISTER_STATIC_SENSOR("dvl", DVLSensor)

instead of: GZ_REGISTER_SENSOR_PLUGIN(DvlPlugin)

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-11-02**:
Would recommend to look here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f4e51e8f64001beda70615ab8982a7d5a4e65b18/gazebo/sensors/?at=default

to see how sensors are implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found this other post: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13966/examples-of-registering-a-custom-sensor-not-plugin/#17653  which help me to make a new sensor for Gazebo. That solution works pretty well.

---

Originally posted by [maikelo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6309/maikelo/) with karma: 26 on 2018-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1